# Matrix computation without for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, networkx, motif

I am newcomer with python. Is there a way to remove all 'for loops' and use matrixes and vectors instead?

```
for trip in u_triplets:
    sub_gr = G.subgraph(trip)
    mot_match = [nx.is_isomorphic(sub_gr, motifs[mot_id]) for mot_id in list(motifs.keys())]
    
    match_keys = [list(motifs.keys())[i] for i in range(len(motifs)) if mot_match[i]]
    
    if len(match_keys) == 1:
        mcount[match_keys[0]] += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): for example, what is `u_triplets`? It would be more helpful is to state, in words, what you expect your code to do, and then provide some example inputs and your expected outputs. That is not to say that your provided code is not helpful, but that it is more difficult to try to interpret it without more explanation.

Comment: Thank you. It is actually my aim to calculate the number of motifs in the *G* graph by using the dictionary which is defined as *motifs = ['S1': nx.DiGraph([(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)])]. Here is the complete code [link](https://gist.github.com/tpoisot/8582648).